# Using configuration in JAVA - best practice

Tags: java, jar, configuration, tomcat7, war

In my case I have:

1. **LangDetector** is java project with **HtmlTags.config** that exported to **LangDetector.jar**.
2. **LangDetectionService** is java jersey service that exported to WAR file. **LangDetectionService** uses **LangDetector.jar** (has reference in buildpath)

When I deploy WAR file on tomcat, I don't see **HtmlTags.config** in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/LangDetectionService.

I tried to add **HtmlTags.config** to **LangDetectionService** also, and after deploying **HtmlTags.config** is in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/LangDetectionService folder, but it doesn't work.

What's wrong here? What's the best practices to do it?

Comment: A few things to check ... first, are you *sure* that `HtmlTags.config` is inside `LangDetector.jar`? Second, are you *sure* that `LangDetector.jar` is in `LangDetectionService.war`? Third, is `LangDetector.jar` in your exploded directory (under `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/LangDetectionService`)? (I'd expect to see your jar in there, still zipped up.) Fourth, you say you don't *see* `HtmlTags.config` where you are expecting it ... but is it actually broken?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. LangDetector.jar is in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/LangDetectionService/WEB-INF/lib after deploying.  4. Maybe not, I want to understand how to take out HtmlTags.config that it will be accessible (like app.config in .NET)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that HtmlTags.config is inside LangDetector.jar. It should be directly under jar file root.
2. Check that LangDetector.jar is inside LandDetectionService war file WEB-INF/lib

If it is like that, HtmlTags.config should be in classpath and readable to your service. But what code should read this HtmlTags.config file is unclear from your question.

You can try to read this file like that:

```
log.debug("HtmlTags.config exists: " + new File("HtmlTags.config").exists());
```

, where log is your logger.

And like always, you should start checking your server and application logs for errors and warnings.

And your question leaves me wonder, why you need to see that file in that directory? If you want to read it from your application, then it should be in classpath. Physical location is not really important, or is it?

Comment: 1. Inside. 2. Inside.  3. "why you need to see that file in that directory" - to change value without complinig new jar. But I don't understand what do you mean in classpath. What do I need to write there? Could you give me example is based on my case?

Comment: I solved it. 1. Add HtmlTags.config to service project. 2. Change line "Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + configName)" to line "Configuration.class.getClassLoader ().getResourceAsStream(configName)" .

Comment: If you intend to write into HtmlTags.config, you shouldn't package it with your application. Instead place it & make it accessible from outside of Tomcat. Otherwise you will be overwriting your configuration file every re-deploy and all the changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It's solution. 1. Add HtmlTags.config to service project. 2. Change line "Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + configName)" to line "Configuration.class.getClassLoader ().getResourceAsStream(configName)" .
3. When LangDetector.jar will load HtmlTags.config it will get it from service project (behavior like in .NET)